# How to know npm package compatibility with Angular version prior install or upgrade?

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I am planning to upgrade existing project from Angular 4 to Angular 7. I have 8-12 packages (other than angular lib) used in project. How do I know in advance whether package is compatible with Angular 7? Below are the packages I am using in Angular 4.

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4": "^0.2.0",
"angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.4.0",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"file-saver": "^1.3.3",
"geolib": "^2.0.24",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"mydatepicker": "^2.6.3",
"ng-pick-datetime": "^5.0.0-beta.10",
"ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.10",
"ngx-chips": "^1.6.5",
"ngx-inactivity": "^1.0.1",
"ngx-loading": "^1.0.8",
"ngx-order-pipe": "^1.1.0",
"ngx-pagination": "^3.0.1",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"xlsx": "^0.11.14",
"xlsx-style": "^0.8.13",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check one by one all these packages on github, open the `package.json` file for each of them and check the `peer-dependencies` property for each of them.

For example, `angular2-modal` package.json looks like this:

```
 ....
 "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^2.1.1"
 },
 ....
```

This means it won't work with any version of angular > 2.

By the way, you are lucky because `npm` and `yarn` will do the dirty job for you. You can just update your angular version and if some peer dependency is not met, then the package manager will alert you with a warning.

> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-animate@^1.5.0 +--
>
> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-aria@^1.5.0 +-- angular-material@1.0.6 +
>
> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular-messages@^1.5.0 `-- mdi@1.4.57`

and you can fix them package by package

Comment: Is there really no automated way to do this in 2022? We have dozens of dependencies in our project and checking package.json for each is extremely time consuming.

Comment: @Forge_7  Hi so how did you solved this I am also in the same situation I have to upgrade from Angular 9 to 15. its a medium size application with alot of dependencies.